# PHPMailer Error on parameters

Tags: php, phpmailer

Trying to send emails with multiple attachments using PHPMailer

require is fine
$mail = new PHPMailer(); is fine 
script stops working when I start adding in the parameters for the mails.

PHP function :

```
function kamp_bulk_mail(){

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';           
$content = mysqli_fetch_array(sql('select','select * from kampen_mailtemplate where kamp = '.$_POST['id']));    
$spelers = sql('select','select * from kampen_spelers where kamp = '.$_POST['id']);
while($spelers_ = mysqli_fetch_array($spelers)){
    echo "1";           
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
    echo "2";           
    $mail->From("test@sender.be");  
    echo "3";       
    $mail->FromName("Admin");
    $mail->addAddress($spelers_['email_voogd']);        
    echo "4";       
    foreach(glob("kampen/configuratie/bijlagen/".$_POST['id']."_*") as $filename){      
        $mail->addAttachment($filename);
    }   
    echo "5";
    $mail->Subject = $content['titel'];
    $mail->Body = $content['content'];
    }
    catch(phpmailerException $e){
        echo $e->errorMesage();
    }
    if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}       

}   
}
```

This echoes 12

EDIT : adjusted code to show where the problem begins

Comment: Your structure is quite inefficient - there's no need to create a new PHPMailer instance every time. The `send` call should be inside your `try` block if you're going to catch exceptions. I suggest you base your code on [the mailing list example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
$mail->addAdress($spelers_['email_voogd']);
```

To

```
$mail->addAddress($spelers_['email_voogd']);
```

Its just a typo I think

[Here is a list of all the method names](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods)